# Rails LIMIT per GROUP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to get records of each category limited to 5, but I ended up returning only 5 records.

How can I translate this sql statement in Rails ActiveRecord?

```
SELECT *
FROM "jobs" a
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM jobs
  WHERE ID = a.ID
) <= 5
AND jobkey_confirmation IS NOT NULL
AND EXTRACT(MONTH from created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH from now())
```

I was just able to do the following, which returned only 5 records as mentioned above:

```
scope :confirmed_this_month, where("jobkey_confirmation IS NOT NULL AND EXTRACT(MONTH from created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH from now())").group("category").limit(5).order("created_at DESC")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use find_by_sql?

```
Job.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM "jobs" a WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE ID = a.ID ) <= 5 AND jobkey_confirmation IS NOT NULL AND EXTRACT(MONTH from created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH from now()))
```

Or are you looking to totally replace it with AR Calls?

-- pulling up code from comment----

```
def self.limited_grouped_jobs 
    find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM jobs a WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE ID = a.ID ) <= 5 AND jobkey_confirmation IS NOT NULL AND EXTRACT(MONTH from created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH from now())")
end
```

Comment: I want to have the statement as a scope so I can call it in the controller. This find_by_sql returns this error: ActionDispatch::Session::SessionRestoreErro

Comment: well you can call find_by_sql from the controller. But are you trying to store the results of the job in the sessions as opposed to IDS?

Comment: Nope. No sessions were used for this query because results are just rendered onto the matching view. Anyway, I don't seem to like having sql statements inside the controller that's why I want to call it using a scope. I hope there is a way for this.

Comment: If you don't want the sql in the Controller, build it as a class method?  as opposed to a scope.

Comment: hi Doon, is this ok? def self.limited_grouped_jobs
    limited_jobs = Job.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM jobs a WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE ID = a.ID ) <= 5 AND jobkey_confirmation IS NOT NULL AND EXTRACT(MONTH from created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH from now())")
  end

Comment: you don't need to call Job.find_by_sql, you can just say find_by_sql inside the self.limited_grouped_jobs and also you probably don't need the local limited_jobs variable.  just return the results of find_by_sql directly.  THat being said if you run it in console does it give you the results you are expecting?

Comment: Thanks Doon. I got my results. Also, I fixed the syntax as you pointed out. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select j.*
from
    jobs j
    inner join (
        select
            row_number() over (partition by category_id order by id) rn,
            id
        from jobs
        where
            jobkey_confirmation IS NOT NULL
            AND EXTRACT(MONTH from created_at) = EXTRACT(MONTH from now())
    ) i on i.id = j.id
where rn <= 5
```